# Embedding webcam images in a page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, scripting, meta-tags

My company has several webcams at our various locations around the world.  Currently we have a page for each city.  Take for example, in Atlanta, we have 128 locations.   I currently am using js to get a new image from the webcam every 7 seconds.   Then I have them all built into separate iframes on the Atlanta page.

I have attached 2 different ways that I have built the original.  One was with a meta tag(this location)[image: this location] that would refresh every 7 seconds.   The other was with JS(that location)[image: that location] that would refresh every 7 seconds but timeout after 46 refreshes. Also attached is the iframe. [image: iframe]

So in a nutshell, there are 128 different iframes on my Atlanta page.  The problem I have is that it is extremely slow to load as it is getting 128 different images every 7 seconds.  On top of that, unless I use internet explorer, it kills my pc's memory as it is just very heavy.  I have some locations that only have like 30 cameras and those refresh very quickly and don't use a ton of memory.   Outside of breaking down my larger markets into 5 or 6 different pages, is there something else that can be done to get the pages to load quicker and be lighter weight?

FYI, the images are of digital billboards and we need to be able to show a customer on demand that their ad is displaying.

Comment: It looks like you have a way to fetch the images directly and individually. Seems like you could have 128 images in your page (rather than iframes) and have javascript update each in rotation. This would likely cut down on resources required as it would remove the many iframe contexts that the browser is maintaining.